# cURL on Linux not compiled, although installed

Tags: linux, centos, php, curl

cURL is not compiled into PHP. I'm running:

```
[root@vps ~]# cat /etc/issue
CentOS release 5.7 (Final)
Kernel \r on an \m
```

Then I execute `yum install curl` and `yum install php-curl`. Then:

```
   [root@vps ~]# which curl
    /usr/bin/curl
   [root@vps ~]# /usr/bin/curl -v
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' for more information
```

My environment still shows that I haven't compile curl into php. Why?

I used `phpinfo()`, which shows:

[image: cURL support: enabled]

but when I install `zencart` on my vps hosting, it shows:

[image: CURL not compiled into PHP - notify server administrator]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Check if by any chance `curl_init()` is on the `disabled_functions` of your php.ini, because from what I see [here](http://zencart.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/zencart/branches/v1-5-0/trunk/zc_install/includes/classes/installer.php?revision=39&view=markup) the Zencart installer checks that.

Also, on a test script (like the one you created for phpinfo()) try this to see what happens:

```
var_dump(curl_init());
```